# Anyway to bypass the config prompt on Icecast installation?

Tags: ubuntu, icecast

On Ubuntu, installting `apt-get install icecast2` will start a prompt to do the default config.

I'm trying to automate the process on installation with a `.sh` script that I could run without looking at it... Is there anyway to bypass the prompt?

Comment: This question rather belongs to https://askubuntu.com and isn't even that icecast specific, as it's about non-interactive package installation.

Comment: @TBR I was conflicted about where to ask to be honest, but I don't feel like it's an OS question, as the prompt is issued by Icecast and since there was a lot of Icecast questions around here already, I took a chance.

Comment: The prompt is issued by the *debian* packaging of Icecast, as devised by the debian multimedia maintainers and used by Ubuntu.

Comment: @TBR I see the nuance. I'll definitely try and go ask there then!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to install and build from the tarball file. I'm leaving this question open so if anyone knows how to without having to build Icecast ourselves.

Comment: That's probably the worst possible alternative.

Comment: @TBR Would you mind explaining your reasoning behind that? I'm curious, since building from tarball is supposed to give me the same final result as the install from the OS, no?

Comment: No, you will miss out on 100% of the distribution integration and on 100% of the security fixes delivered through updated packages. I *maintain* the Icecast source, yet I don't have any systems with source installs, everything is package based.